# Is it halal to design or sell a phone (which can access porn, music, games, etc.)?

Tags: halal-haram, technology

A mobile phone has access to porn, music, movies, animations and games all are haram.

First question is, **is it halal to sell such a device?** as you are not selling porn itself. I am assuming yes, as anything may have potential to be haram. However this is where it becomes a problem for me, what if your designing the mobile. Or media player (ipod mp4), you have the absolute power to block porn access and music access and games with animations access. But you know if you do this it will be a unsuccessful phone. However you are not promoting these harams, but just designing the phone without actively blocking these for popularity and success and leave it to the customers choice. I will never promote people listening to music, but I understand if I block something like that the phone will be virtually a weak and unpopular device where as if you leave the freedom of it.

The Muslim who fears Allah and the one who is neglectful can decide what they want to do.

Comment: You are not responsible for the buyers actions which the device. You could do alot of Good like alot of Bad. What you should look into is your intention when selling the device. And Allah (swt) knows best.

Answer (score 1):

`is it halal to sell such a device`

It is halal for you to make and sell such devices. Phones, computers, TV's etc. can all be used for good or bad. It is up to the end user to decide how to use it.

If the end user uses it for Haram, then he would be the one that minor sinned.

The same is true for anything else - example a knife can be used to terrorize someone or to cook, the making of it is Halal but the end usage can be halal or haram.

Additionally you should never force your opinions/rulings on others. For example you think music is haram, millions of Muslims think otherwise. Same goes for other things.

Answer (score 1):

No device is haram or halal. Its the use of the device that makes it halal or haram. Why don't you think that one can also learn about Islam through phones.internet,cds and movies ? One can also gain knowledge about his field through these devices which can be very useful to human beings.

Answer (score 0):

As a general Islamic rule, product the things or instruments which are related to haram acts, is considered as a haram act. Of course there are some things (instrument) which directly cannot be considered as haram instrument (although some people can abuse them). For instance a person is selling knifes (which are used in cutting foods and fruits), so we cannot say that he is doing a haram act, because people can use it in killing..

But there are some instruments which primarily could be considered for haram act, then it would be counted as a haram trade. In the mentioned issue, you ought to pay attention that if the result of your act directly is related to the use of haram acts or not, if not, there couldn’t be problem, otherwise...

Of course according to the above-mentioned matter, for more caution you can leave it. Another significant point is your intention. Actually your intention ought to be for making an instrument for people to do their halal jobs, not haram.

**To see more related questions/answers, and likewise asking your question:**

- http://www.islamquest.net/

Answer (score -1):

Music is haram, so try hard to avoid it. Alcohol is not haram, unless intended to be made khamr. Any device is not haram, unless intended to be made as bridge to haram content.

As some device have greater good cause than bad, it probably allowed. Just be careful.

And Allah know best

Comment: "Alcohol is not haram", where does it say so?

Comment: @servantofWiser Alcohol is only haram if used for food. But for non food chemical solution, it is allowed. The prophet didn't say that, the prophet said that selling grapes is allowed, but if you know that the grapes is going to be made as khamr, you are not allowed to sell it.

Answer (score -1):

You are responsible for your actions, if I sell you a gun for example you either keep it for self-defence, or you go and murder somebody with it.

I sell you the gun for a good intention for you to defend yourself or your family.
But if you abuse it you are responsible for your actions.